# pg_escape_bytea and apostrophes

Tags: php, postgresql

I am using the function `pg_escape_bytea()` and I have seen that apostrophes inside strings are duplicated. Is there any way to unescape this back?

For example, if I do:

```
pg_escape_bytea("asdiajsojdas O'Donnel dasdasdasdasda")
```

and pass it through INSERT or UPDATE in a prepared statement when I got back the binary data, the apostrophes of the strings are duplicated.

Comment: The only reason to do this is to insert into a database and only 1 will be inserted into the database.  The first one `escapes` the second.

Comment: The fact is that when I select the string from the database I got both of them.

Comment: Then you double escaped somewhere.

Comment: How are you using `pg_escape_string` when you INSERT or UPDATE?

Comment: I am using `$rawdata = pg_escape_bytea($rawdata)` and passing $rawdata to the INSERT statement. But inside $rawdata there are strings with apostrophes.

Answer (score 1):

Finally I solved it with

```
$escaped_data = str_replace(array("\\\\", "''"), array("\\", "'"), $data);
```

It seems like it is a known behaviour of the function: http://php.net/manual/es/function.pg-escape-bytea.php#89036